# Borderlands 2 in True Vault Hunter Mode, does Madame von Bartlesby always drop a legendary weapon?

Tags: borderlands-2

I'm playing in TVHM and just finished the first part of the Tiny Tina quest "You Are Cordially Invited: Party Prep" where you have to retrieve Sir Reginald from Madame von Bartlesby.  I blasted her from a distance, using a sniper rifle from the Tundra Express map entry area, instead of dealing with her directly on Skittering Mound.  Her body dropped at the foot of the mountain, and there was no loot at all.  I was expecting some sort of legendary item, specifically the Baby Maker.  Did I mess up by not killing her on Skittering Mound?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Drops in Borderlands 2 are almost always chance-based. In particular, legendary item drops usually only have about a 1 in 30 chance of actually dropping.

Gearbox Software have actually blogged about the drops recently. See [this article](http://www.gearboxsoftware.com/community/articles/1087), and [its follow-up](http://www.gearboxsoftware.com/community/articles/1092/inside-the-box-evolution-of-loot).

Comment: Thanks for the article links.  Looks like I'm going to have to restart from a recent save and try again -- maybe up to 30 times.  :-)

Comment: @Alan, or just keep killing her. Once you turn in the quest, she'll respawn every time you save and exit. As a rule, all bosses generally will.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that will save me hours of replay!  Turns out the last game save I had offloaded to my USB drive was after completing the Mighty Morphin' quest, and I had spent a lot of time in Tundra Express locating and deactivating Tiny Tina's mines.